# Origin of "Everybody is smarter than anybody"?

Tags: phrases, catch-phrases

Who said this:

> Everybody is smarter than anybody.

I have been trying to find the origin of this phrase with no success. I think I first heard it from a speaker on an IT subject (but I am not sure if its origin is from a person with a technology background).

I would like to use this quote but won't use it if I can't give a proper attribution.

Comment: Are you sure it's the right way round?

Comment: @Peter Yes, it's the right way round. It means that collectively, we're better than each of us separately. Synergy. Like what SE does :)

Comment: The Demotivator folks have my favorite take on this quote: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsgjo.jpg

Comment: @Peter Taylor - Perhaps you are thinking of the variant I posted in my answer below?

Comment: @T.E.D., similar sentiments, although expressed about crowds (or mobs) rather than meetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dates back to at least 1949, where it is referenced in these [conference proceedings](http://books.google.com/books?id=888WAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Everybody%20is%20smarter%20than%20anybody%22&dq=%22Everybody%20is%20smarter%20than%20anybody%22&hl=en&ei=4aX4TdXlAYqYOq_L8bYK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwADgK) with attribution to [Carl Sandburg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sandburg) (1878 – 1967):

[image]

I've also heard it as "all of us are better than one of us", which dates at from the [late nineties](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%20%22all%20of%20us%20are%20better%20than%20one%20of%20us%22&btnG=Search%20Books#q=%22all%20of%20us%20are%20better%20than%20one%20of%20us%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ei=I6X4Tb3GHJHpObvPhK4K&ved=0CBgQpwUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=86fb37c16210b855&biw=1920&bih=1061).

---

Edit: Carl Sandburg's original line is "Everybody is cleverer than anybody", published in 1936's [*The People, Yes*](http://books.google.com/books?id=qVFbAAAAMAAJ&q=inauthor:%22Carl%20Sandburg%22%20%22Everybody%20is%20cleverer%20than%20anybody%22&dq=inauthor:%22Carl%20Sandburg%22%20%22Everybody%20is%20cleverer%20than%20anybody%22&hl=en&ei=QKj4Tc_nBs2SOri51KsK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg). (You can read a bit more of it in this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=bCSu8UHz9EUC&pg=PA495&dq=inauthor:%22Carl%20Sandburg%22%20%22Everybody%20is%20cleverer%20than%20anybody%22&hl=en&ei=QKj4Tc_nBs2SOri51KsK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=inauthor:%22Carl%20Sandburg%22%20%22Everybody%20is%20cleverer%20than%20anybody%22&f=false).)

[image]

---

Edit 2: And "everybody is cleverer than anybody" goes to back [1877](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22Everybody%20is%20cleverer%20than%20anybody%22&btnG=Search%20Books#q=%22Everybody%20is%20cleverer%20than%20anybody%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=hqr4TevDFoqa8QPr0KXaCw&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=86fb37c16210b855&biw=1920&bih=1018), where it is referenced by several Westminster publications as an "epigram of Talleyrand" or "Talleyrand's famous sentence". This is the French diplomat [Charles Maurice de Talleyrand-Périgord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Maurice_de_Talleyrand-P%C3%A9rigord) (1754 – 1838). I've not found the original French, but it has also been translated as:

> “There is one body that knows more than anybody, and that is everybody”

Comment: Wow! This is my first question here and I am very impressed. Thanks.